# Socket Code Broken in NaCl

Tags: sockets, google-nativeclient

I have a large amount of existing BSD socket code that I have ported to NaCl. I am able to build, link and run this code however the NaCl module crashes as soon as the socket code is reached.

I am now using `nacl_io`, but when I try to call TCP connect function I get an error with `errno 38` which means

```
#define ENOSYS      38  /* Function not implemented */
```

Why would calling the `connect` function fail but I am able to successfully resolve host via `gethostbyname()`?

Note that I am using the example code from `nacl_io` demo. That code in the demo works fine, but when copied to my own project I get the errors when calling `connect()`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you call nacl_io_init_ppapi function first, connect() should not return ENOSYS.

I originally had nacl_io in the make file listed after pthread. moving nacl_io to the front of the linker list fixed this issue.

nacl_io defines few functions which are defined in libpthread as well. If libpthread is listed before nacl_io then functions from libpthread are used, if it's listed after nacl_io then functions from nacl_io are used.